# How do I correct the segmentation fault of my code below?

Tags: c++, debugging

i was trying this solution for a problem on [codeforces](https://codeforces.com/contest/1303/problem/A)

it showed a segmentation fault in my code and i don't know any single thing about segmentation fault.

what should i do??

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);

    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        int z=0;
        string::iterator itr=s.begin();
        while(*itr!='1')itr++;
        while(*itr)
        {
            if(*itr=='0')z++;
            itr++;
        }
        itr--;
        while(*itr!='1')
        {
            itr--;
            z--;
        }
        cout<<z<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debug your code, step by step.

Comment: First figure out *where* in your code you get it, by using a debugger to catch it. A hint: To check for reaching the end of the string always compare your iterator against the containers or strings end iterator. And of course don't decrement the `begin` iterator.

Comment: `while(*itr!='1')itr++;` What happens if there is no `1` in the string?

Answer (score 1):

Never assume `itr` is dereferenceable.

See the following updated block of code.

```
while( itr != s.end() && *itr != '1')itr++; // Check itr != s.end()

while(itr != s.end() && *itr != '\0' )      // Same check
{
   if(*itr == '0')z++;
   itr++;
}
itr--;

while(itr != s.begin() && *itr != '1')      // Check itr != s.begin()
{
   itr--;
   z--;
}
```